# Parsing data from a file and storing in an object

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11

OK so I had a job interview with a coding challenge which I completely blew..

I am hoping someone can help me solve this so that I can at least understand what I was missing so I can do better next time something like this comes up.

I was asked to create a parser for the following data:

```
Data = {
    Name = "Macrosoft",
    Launched = 2006,
    Scores = {
        Players = {
            Josh = 46,
            June = 98
        },
        Rewards = ( 50, 40, 20 ),
        Min = 1,
        Max = 100
    },
    Games = (
        "Evo",
        "Gun Star",
        "Nuka"
    )
}
```

required functions:

- `data.GetStr("Name"); // returns Macrosoft`
- `data.GetNum("Launched"); // returns 2006`
- `data.GetData("Scores").GetData("Players").GetNum("June"); // returns 98`
- `data.GetArray("Games").GetStr(1); // returns Evo`
- `data.FindNum("June"); // returns 98`

Details:

All elements have an identifier like Data, Name, Launched, etc.

All elements have some data which come after the identifier and the char '=' the data can be:

- String
- Int (Launched, Min and Max)
- array ( arrays defined between '(' and ')' )
- other data (Data, Scores, Players)

Comment: strikingly close to json, just replace `=` -> `:` `()` -> `[]` and `string` -> `"string"` and use a json parser! jk

Comment: And the question is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a data structure to hold your data. According to the data structure you post, I think you can define a class like this:

```
class Data {
public:
    Data(string str);

    string GetStr(string key);
    int GetNum(string key);
    Data GetData(string key);
    Data GetArray(string key);

    // Array data operations
    string GetStr(int index);
    int GetNum(int index);

private:
    map<string, Data> dataMap;
};
```

Generally you should split your data file first, you can split your data string with character ',', then you will get some assigment statements like: `Name = "str"`, `Launched = 123456`, `Scores = { ... }` and `Games = ( ... )`.

Then something like `Name = "str"` and `Launched = 123456` can be put into `dataMap` directly. Things like `Scores = { ... }` and `Games = ( ... )` should be put into a new `Data` variable, then make `Socres` and `Games` be keys to the new `Data` variables and put them into `dataMap`.

So the next problem we should solve is how to initialize a `Data` object with `Scores = { ... }` and `Games = ( ... )`.

You can see that `Scores = { ... }` is exactly what you want to solve, so you can just call Data constructor.

Then `Games = ( ... )` should splitted by ',' again. You can also put elements in `( ... )` into `dataMap`, and keys should be the element's index in `( ... )`

Now everything is clear. Your constructor function may like this:

```
Data(string str) {
    vector<string> vecStr = split(str, ',');
    for(auto vecIter = vecStr.begin(); vecIter != vecStr.end(); ++vecIter) {
        if (ifIsArrayAssignment(*vecIter)) {
            // Games = ( ... )
            // you should put every elements into a new Data's dataMap
            // the key to the value can be numbers: 1 2 3 ...
        } else if (ifIsDataAssignment(*vecIter)) {
            // Scores = { ... }
            // you should get the key from *vecIter first
            // and make a new Data object with { ... } part
        } else {
           // Lanched = 123456 or Name = "str"
           // put it into dataMap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. 
Parsing data has never been something I really grasped but this makes thing a lot clearer for me. So much so that I think I can handle everything else.